# is there an alternative method to json.parser for ie

Tags: javascript

I am using ie8 and so does everybody else. I need to make this script work for ie8. I cannot make json.parser work on IE. I tryied some of the recommendations that I saw here like json2.js modify html file etc. It does not seem to be working. Is there an alternative to this method? I really need this working and cannot figure out.

get_cpu.php outputs the data as this:

[1230000000,23]

This is my function. It works on chrome, firefox but not IE.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 function request_cpu_Data() {

    $.ajax({

        url: 'get_cpu.php', 
        success: function(data) {
        alert(data.length);
                var myObj = JSON.parse(data); 
                var point = cpu_chart.series[0].points[0];
                var newVal=myObj[1];
        myDate=myObj[0];
        point.update(newVal);

        setTimeout(request_cpu_Data, 1000000); 
        },
        cache: false

    });
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code which causes you an error? And are you sure that you are using `JSON.parse` written with those capital letters?

Comment: json2.js works fine in IE8...

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/09/10/native-json-in-ie8.aspx

Comment: what version of jquery are you using? why aren't you returning a json mime type?

Comment: @dandavis, I downlaoded json2.js from git and included in my file, I dont see any difference. Where did you get your version?

Comment: an error message that IE gives would be helpful. then, is your browser in IE7 compatibility mode?

Comment: @Daniel A. White, I am using jquery version 1.8.2, any ideas how I would address this issue. I am stuck.

Comment: ie8 does have JSON, so you dont need json2.js

Comment: @akonsu, IE says there is a sytax error on this line: var myObj = JSON.parse(data);

Comment: maybe it just cannot parse the data? that is why it gives syntax error?

Comment: @dandavis, when I open the html that include this javascript in chrome it works like a charm. On ie it does not work.

Comment: what is the value of `data`?

Comment: @akonsu, data is the values return from the get_cpu.php script [120000,4]

Comment: I am saying that it possibly throws an exception because it cannot parse the data that your server returns. return something else and see if it works.

Comment: @akonsu, is this line correct: var myObj = JSON.parse(data); IE saying syntax error

Comment: this line seems correct. IE might be saying 'syntax error' because it thinks that the json string has a syntax error.

Comment: comment out this line and insert `var myObj = JSON.parse('{}');` and see if it works

Comment: I dont get error, alert(myObj) returns object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It possibly throws an exception because it cannot parse the data that your server returns.

I suspect IE8's implementation cannot parse JSON arrays.

You can try this, for example: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

Comment: so, how I should the server return the values to ie?

Comment: try returning `{data: [120000,4]}`. if this does not work either then return the contents of your array as an object: `{elem0: 120000, elem1: 4}`. I do not know, play with it and see what works.

Comment: you might be able to delete JSON; then load json2.js. If JSON already exists, json2.js does nothing. if you can kill the native JSON, then it should be using the json2.js's parser instead of the faulty native one.